# python function capitalize first letter only

Tags: python, python-3.x, uppercase, capitalize

I need build a function to transform 1st character only, from any word but also this function need address the problem if the 1st character from the word doesn't starts with a character, for example '_sun',' -tree', '2cat' these words need be like _Sun, -Tree, 2Cat. This is what I have so far, it can convert any word but I don't know how do 2nd part, need use ASCII?? to get value of 1st character and see if the word starts with character?

```
def convert(capital):
    return capital[0].upper() + capital[1:]

def main():
   print(convert('sun'))

main()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function capitalises the first character, regardless.

For this task, you'll have to find the first character in a different way; you could use [`str.isalpha()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha):

```
def convert(capital):
    index = 0
    while index < len(capital) and not capital[index].isalpha():
        index += 1
    return capital[:index] + capital[index:].capitalize()
```

Another approach would be to use a [regular expression-based substitution](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#search-and-replace); you'll have to use a function to uppercase the character found:

```
import re

def convert(capital):
    return re.sub(r'([a-z])(.*)$', lambda m: m.group(1).upper() + m.group(2),
                  capital, flags=re.I)
```

This matches case-insensitively on the first letter, and replaces that with the uppercase version.

A third idea is to use [`str.title()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.title), which does the same for *all* words in a text, but only apply it to the first word:

```
def convert(capital):
    first, _, rest = capital.partition(' ')
    return '{} {}'.format(first.title(), rest)
```

Comment: It's too bad `str.title` doesn't accept an agument for "number of words to capitalize".  That'd be perfect here :-)

Comment: @mgilson: you can still use it, but you'd have to split on the first space. Added that in.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use a regex and limit it to 1 replacement, eg:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub('[a-zA-Z]', lambda m: m.group().upper(), '2cat', 1)
'2Cat'
>>> re.sub('[a-zA-Z]', lambda m: m.group().upper(), 'sun', 1)
'Sun'
```

Answer (score 0):

You only seem to have either a word starting with a letter or where the second character is a letter so you just have two possibilities:

```
print(s.capitalize() if s[0].isalpha() else s[0] +  s[1:].capitalize())
```

Comment: This is rather limited though; I'm sure the OP will come back and ask about *but what about `'_-sun'`*?

Comment: @MartijnPieters, *I need build a function to transform 1st character only from any word but also this function need address the problem if the 1st character from the word doesn't starts with a character*  , that is what the code does.

Comment: Sure, it solves that problem. But it seldom ever is that simple.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, well  i will leave that  to the OP to decide.